# Download link not working in Adobe AIR app

Tags: air

I wanted to let users browse my site as a desktop application,
but didn't have the time to write an application from scratch.
SO tried following trick.
Created a simple Adobe AIR application with a single page. 
This page redirects to my website and hence loads the website in the AIR window.

Everything is working fine except that the download links are not working. The download doesn't start. Nothing happens. What is the solution here?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Adobe AIR doesn't support downloading from a link.
But it does provide you the option to open a link in your default browser. I am using this now.

Comment: Can you provide an example or a reference to how this is done?