# Adobe air - download links not working

Tags: air

I'm trying to turn a website of mine into an executable for Windows with Adobe Air.

Everything seems to be in order, but I couldn't quite figure out how to save a file from a download link.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919855/download-link-not-working-in-adobe-air-app) that is suggesting that this is not supported by air, but it is possible to download links via an installed browser (IE for example?)

I also tried to search the official documation and found that there are [loading external data possibilites](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfd.html) but as I didn't see a way to save the incoming result locally, i couldn't get that to work.

1) How can I accomplish this? Are there working code examples available anywhere?
2) How can I make files download on a web browser from an AIR app?
3) What other options do I have?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get a download to work with the HTMLLoader class too.

The only working solution might be to start the download with a browser.

```
var url:String = "site.com/download.zip";
var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest(url);
navigateToURL(request, '_blank');
```